# How to get active directory userid from a string field of a work item

Tags: c#, xml, tfs, workitem

By synchronizing a project plan from a MS Project .mpp to TFS, I want to sync a field that is a string representing the name of the project manager affected to a project. As a rule, this string is taken from Active Directory's valid users group in TFS.

I am searching for a way to obtain the userid as well in order to query a SQL Server DB. Is there a was to get the userid from AD when you have the user's name? This seems to be an option, whereas not the best.

If there would be a way to capture the userid in this field as well at the same time that i sync the project manager's full name, this would be the best alternative. Any suggestions?

```
<FIELD name="Project Manager" refname="Custom.ProjectManager" type="String" reportable="dimension">
<HELPTEXT>The name of the project manager.</HELPTEXT>
<SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">
  <LISTITEM value="[global]\Project Collection Valid Users" />
</SUGGESTEDVALUES>
</FIELD>
```

Comment: Why do you need the user ID? if your goal is presenting a list of project managers, why not expanding a group defined in AD?

Comment: Where would you resolve the UserID? In the config file, or in a C# assembly?

Comment: @KMoraz, I need the user ID to query the database to find the records associated with this PM. I suppose I could just use the full name instead of the user ID, but in practice it's always better to user the user ID to identify a user.

Comment: @code4life, I was thinking in the TFS work item config file

Comment: I don't know the TFS config file very well, but do you have access to the environment variables? For instance, `USERDOMAIN`, `USERDNSDOMAIN`, and `USERNAME`? Those variables are set during user login, so saves you the call to `DirectoryServices`.

Comment: @code4life, if you're talking about how to obtain the USERID from AD in c#, heres how I do it: `ContextHelper.GetCurrentThreadUserIdentity().ToUpper();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround I tought of. The downside is that the USERID is shown whenever you see the name of the project manager.

**Work item type XML file**

```
    <FIELD name="Project Manager" refname="Custom.ProjectManager" type="String" reportable="dimension">
    <HELPTEXT>The name of the project manager.</HELPTEXT>
    <SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">
      <LISTITEM value="(ID='DOEJ24') John Doe " />
      <LISTITEM value="(ID='DOEJ23') Jane Doe " />
      <LISTITEM value="(ID='SMIJ03') John Smith " />
      <LISTITEM value="(ID='COSG01') George Constanza " />
      <LISTITEM value="(ID='BRAT99') Tom Brady " />
    </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
    </FIELD>
```

**C#**

```
    var projectManager = WorkItemStore.GetWorkItem(Convert.ToInt32(id))["Project Manager"]);
    var pmUserId = projectManager.SubString(5, 6);
```

This way I can easily query my database which has the project manager user id column.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(yourDomain, IdentityType.Name, fullName);
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... The original question was how to find userid from the work item's string field. The problem is that both work item fields "Assigned To" and "ChangedBy" return a string corresponding to user's name such as "John Smith". How can we find userid (or username) or email from this? I had to solve this task recently. The solution was - talking to DirectoryServices, find UserPrincipal object for the user, this object will contain userid (SamAccountName), EmailAddress and whole lot more for the user. The actual solution was a bit longer, I can provide if interested

Comment: +1 sorry for the confusion & welcome to StackOverflow. It's preferable to provide some text along side the code that describes what it does. Your description you've provided here in the comments would be perfect to add to the answer to give it some context instead of a code snippet standing alone.